# Akka (JVM) event-sourcing in Azure?

Tags: azure, akka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

I am trying to deploy an Akka application on Azure, that uses the journal persistence plugin.

I cannot find a working combination when it comes to the persistence plugin I should use. 
So far I looked into:

- akka-persistence-mongo and Azure Document Store with Mongo driver: it does not work because akka-persistence-mongo is not compatible with the latest reactive-mongo version that supports SSL
- akka-persistence-jdbc and an Azure SQL server: it seems the akka-persistence-jdbc is only compatible with Slick H2, Oracle and MySQL drivers

I do not have any strong performance requirements, this is why both solutions would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess for the moment is akka-persistence-redis with Microsoft Azure Redis. 
I am proposing a contribution to this plugin to make it compatible with Microsoft Azure Redis (authentication, as well as a strange error when calling zrangebyscore that I do not have with a local Redis).